# How do I cycle through Chrome windows of a specific profile using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, google-chrome

I'm using the following function in Hammerspoon to find tabs in Chrome for arbitrary URLs. If the URLs can't be found, then a new tab is opened. Mostly I use this to tabs I care about with a keyboard shortcut. This all works fine except for on my home machine where I have a couple of different Chrome profiles open. It always seems to cycle through the windows of other the profile that is open, rather than using my default profile.

I've been searching and I'm not clear on whether it's possibly to cycle through only the windows belonging to a specific profile.

So, below is a `lua` function which runs `AppleScript`. I'm guessing the issue is somewhere around `activate`. I've included the `applescript_action()` function for the sake of completeness.

```
local function chrome_tab_action(url_substring, url_to_visit_if_tab_not_found)
    return applescript_action(
        [[

      tell application "Google Chrome"
          activate

          set foundWindow to false
          set theTabIndex to -1

          repeat with theWindow in every window
              set theTabIndex to 0
              repeat with theTab in every tab of theWindow
                  set theTabIndex to theTabIndex + 1
                  if theTab's URL contains "]] ..
        url_substring ..
        [[" then
                      set foundWindow to theWindow
                      set foundTabIndex to theTabIndex
                  end if
              end repeat
          end repeat

          if foundWindow is not false then
              set foundWindow's active tab index to foundTabIndex
              set index of foundWindow to 1
          else
              open location "]] ..
        url_to_visit_if_tab_not_found .. [["
          end if

      end tell

    ]]
    )
end

local applescript_action = function(script)
      return function()
          hs.osascript.applescript(script)
    end
end
```